# Angular Cli- In StyleURL add a css file located in the node_module directory

Tags: angular, components, angular-cli, node-modules, blocking

I am running my front-end application using the [Angular-Cli](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-cli/info).

I want to add a css file from the `node_module` only to that specific component. I do not want to add the CSS file to the Angular.cli.json `"scripts": []` array,

I have the following component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({  
    selector: 'fbsign-component',
    templateUrl: './fb.signin.component.html',

    styleUrls: ['./fb.signin.component.css', '../../node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css'] })

export class FbSigninComponent{

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(): any{}

    onClick(){
        window.location.href ="http://localhost:1337/facebook"
    }
}
```

I think that the something is blocking the `styleURLs[]` from accessing the CSS files located in `node_module` directory.

How do I unblock it?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

the below home.component.ts file is following the location in my project

src => app => home

here my **home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css', '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can load it dynamically.

```
ngOnInit() 
{
    this.loadStyle('your path');
 } 

     loadStyle(src)
  {
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = src;
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  let links = head.getElementsByTagName('link');
  let style = head.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
  head.insertBefore(link, style);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to use ViewEncapsulation.None in order to make this component accessible for the styles from node modules. Try add this to your component decorator:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({  
    selector: 'fbsign-component',
    templateUrl: './fb.signin.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './fb.signin.component.css',
        '../../node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css'
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class FbSigninComponent{
}
```

another option is to add these external styles into *angular.json*:
**architect**->**build**->**options**

```
"options": [
    ...
    "styles": [
        "./node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css",
        "src/styles.scss"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your directory structure correct?
To access files, outside your current folder, use "../"

Another reason might be that you are trying to access styles inside a child component while they should be inserted in the parent component where the component is injected using the selector, to get the proper layout.

So, try adding the styles to the component where you are using 'fbsign-component' as a selector.